# Cannot Start Weblogic Managed Server,

Tags: weblogic

We are running Weblogic 7sp6. We have a working single node cluster with an Admin and two Managed servers. We are re-creating a 2nd standalone cluster on a 2nd server. We reinstalled Weblogic and have copied over all the configuration files to make thing. Its the same on both clusters. We changed all the references to IP and hostnames. We have used this method before without problems.

In the current case I can startup the Admin which listens on port 7001,7002. But when I try and startup either of the Managed servers it tells me that myserver1/2 is already up. (Managed Servers). I confirmed that myserver is configured to use port 7012,7013 and I cannot find any port conflicts especially because these exact ports worked on the first cluster. Any ideas of what else to look at? I have logged in the admin console and can see the ports are all unique. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The startmanagedweblogic.cmd file had the wrong IP for the Admin IP.